# Gmail API - Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account to single user

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to access emails of an email address in custom domain(my.name@example.com) in google apps. I created service account but I get following error message when trying to read e-mails:

> Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope
>   in request.", Uri:""

I found that I have to [delegate](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) domain-wide authority to the service account. According to my understanding, after delegating, the service account will have access to all e-mail addresses in the domain(eg; john@example.com, sam@example.com ...). Is my understanding correct. If yes, is there a way that service account has access (can be impersonated) to only one e-mail address in the domain?

Comment: When you impersonate an account to service account, only you have access to that account. If you dont want to access certain accounts then dont impersonate those accounts.

Comment: But I can impersonate as any account just by e-mail address. I want to prevent this

Comment: I also have the similar issue, i can impersonate other users in boxes in same domain just by knowing their mail id

Answer (score 0):

Have you authorized the Client Name and the API scopes in the GSuite admin console? It is required for the service account to work and the error you received seems to be related to the API access permissions.

More info at:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en