# "domain wide authority" give access to user data without consent?

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

Very straightforward question, but info on this is conflicting.

We're being asked to create a **service account** that has **domain-wide authority** to access **Gmail API**.

I would like to clarify if that app will now have access to all user data or it will need to seek permission from each individual user?

On one hand I setup a consent screen, on the other I see the following notice when delegating domain wide authority in G suite

> Developers can register their web applications and other API clients
> with Google to enable access to data in Google services like Gmail.
> You can authorize these registered clients to access your user data
> **without your users having to individually give consent or thei**r
> **passwords**.

And here it also seems like the app will have access to all users' data without having to seek it from each user individually: https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

Sorry if it's a dumb question I looked at the SO solutions and read through the documentation, but it's still unclear, closest I found is this: [Gmail API - Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account to single user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354498/gmail-api-delegating-domain-wide-authority-to-the-service-account-to-single-us) but it doesn't answer the question.

[image]

This is what I got from G Suite support, basically saying the app will have access to all the user data without asking for any login/pass:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question:

I would like to clarify if that app will now have access to all user data or it will need to seek permission from each individual user?

#### Answser:

The Service Account will be able to access all data from any user in the domain **without asking for their authorization**.

If you delegate domain-wide authority to a Service Account, this Service Account will be able to **impersonate** any account in the domain. That is, it will be able to **act on behalf of** any account, and access the same resources that this account can access, **no authorization required**.

That's because Service Accounts, even when not using domain-wide delegation, use the "two-legged OAuth" workflow, in which users are not directly involved and consent from them is not required. That's one of the points of Service Accounts. See [this two-legged OAuth diagram](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/2-legged-oauth-diagram.png), in constrast to [the three-legged one](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/admin/en/cpanel/3-legged-oauth-diagram.png).

Of course, this is a very powerful tool, and that's the reason **only domain administrators can grant domain-wide delegation**.

Beware, once you have granted domain-wide authority to a Service Account, you should specify, in your app, which user you want the Service Account to impersonate. If you don't do that, it's like you haven't granted domain-wide authority at all.

I'd suggest you to give a long read to [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [How authorized access works](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2538798)

Answer (score 0):

I'll wait for others to answer, but this is what I got from G Suite support, basically saying the **app will have access to all the user data without asking for any login/pass**

[image]