# Accessing Gmail API using service account

Tags: google-oauth

During the process of creating a service account to access Gmail API, I found that Domain wide delegation to the service account is required. But, this will allow the service account to access all the mailboxes in the domain. Is it possible to put some restriction on the service account so that it can access only certain mailbox/mailboxes.

I couldn't find any workaround to put some restriction on the service account. I am expecting a way to put some mailbox reading restrictions on the service account.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure domain wide deligation you will need to also configure the user on the domain that the service account will be allowed to impersonate.

Then in your code you will need to supply the email address of that user in the domain.

The service account will then be able to run as that user sending emails from that users account and reading emails from it.

it can only access accounts it has been configured to access

Comment: I also have similar issue, where by giving domain wide access to the service account, I can read mails of other mail ids just by knowing the mail id of theirs in the same domain

Same issue was reported here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354498/gmail-api-delegating-domain-wide-authority-to-the-service-account-to-single-us

I cannot find anywhere how to restrict

Comment: can you add an [example]